# Why do I get - 'function' : not all control paths return a value in C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to learn the basics of C using 'The C Programming Language - Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie'

I've created this basic program to try out functions and storing a string, but for some reason getline keeps keeps returning an error. Im using Visual Express 2010 and I keep getting a ''getline' : not all control paths return a value'

I've picked it over and over but just cant see the problem,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
#define LINEWIDTH 80

int getline(char line[], int maxline);

main(){

int length;
int max;
char line[MAXLINE];

max = 0;
while((length = getline(line, MAXLINE)) >0)
if (length>max){
    max=length;
}
if(max>0)
    printf("%s",line);
return 0;
 }


int getline(char line[], int maxline){

int c, i;

for(i = 0; i<maxline-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; i++){

    line[i] = c;
    if (c=='\n'){
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    line[i] ='\0';
    return i;

    }
}
```

Comment: Because it might be that the for loop won't be executed, causing the function to return nothing.

Comment: You can't declare main() the way you do, the C standard does not allow it. This is why you shouldn't use old dinosaur books to learn C.

Comment: Second edition K&R does indeed have `main()` without the explicit return type required by C99 (p72 for instance, to pull open the book at one page pretty much at random — it happened to have a `main()` on it).  Sadly, this reduces its value...it is an excellent book, but it documents an older style of C programming (which is not dreadfully surprising; it was written a decade before the C99 standard was released).

Comment: If maxline is <= 1 you will never return an int value.. Always check for boundary conditions. Also +1 for " learn the basics of C using 'The C Programming Language - Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie'"...Ur doing it right if ur learning from this book!

Comment: Ah, It had fantastic reviews on Amazon however a couple of the problems i've had have been down to the code being out of date. I'll finish of the book before proceeding but any suggestions on good up to date resources?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also if you open any random page, you will find plenty of typos, bugs, non-standard code or poor programming practice. To take your p72: The book describes an outdated way of how variables are declared, that does not correspond to the standard. Then it shows a non-standard function without return type. Then follows an inaccurate description of which variables that are automatically initialized to zero (should be "variables with static storage duration").

Comment: @RamBhat Indeed! Which particular error of the countless ones in the book do you find to be the most beneficial for learning C?

Comment: @Lundin: it documented the C of its era; its era, though, was 25 years ago (1988 copyright date).  C has progressed since then, and C99 is more rigorous than C89 was, and C2011 is much the same as C99 in the relevant areas.  It was a great book; it did its job compactly and efficiently.  It is no longer a great book for learning C from.  [C Programming: A Modern Approach](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-A-Modern-Approach/dp/0393969452) by K N King is a reasonable modern alternative, but more verbose than K&R.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, and the C of the era was pre-standard "K&R C", not C89. The 2nd edition of the book is still full of errors, even for C89.

Comment: Get in the habit of always putting `{}` braces around the bodies of `while`, `for`, `if`, etc. This will save you from potential mistakes, and makes your code easier to read. Also, use an editor that indents code, and paste it here with proper indentation.

Comment: @Barmar Stop giving good advice that counters the bad advise from K&R!

Comment: @Lundin: which errors are you claiming on p72 of K&R 2?  I don't see what you're complaining about.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 4.8 `Declarations of variables (including initializations) may follow the left brace that introduces any compound statement`. Incorrect, variables may be declared anywhere. 4.8 `f(double x)`, non-standard function definition. 4.9 `external and static variables are guaranteed to be initialized to zero`, more accurately this should be worded "variables with static storage duration", since an extern variable cannot be initialized from the scope where it is declared as extern.

Comment: You are criticizing a book for not being prescient about a future standard — a standard a decade in the future from when it was written. That is ridiculous. In C89, that was a correct statement about where variables could be declared; that was also a legitimate declaration of function `f`. There's a difference between 'an external variable' and 'an `extern` declaration of a variable'; you are picking the wrong fight there. Also, those examples are not on p72. I agree that K&R is no longer a good book to learn C from, but you are making false claims about it. Please don't; you'll offend people.

Answer (score 4):

One problem is that you've not copied the code from p29 of K&R Second Edition accurately.

The `getline()` function there is:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for(i = 0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; i++)  // -- No brace! {
        s[i] = c;

    if (c=='\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] ='\0';
    return i;
    // Brace not needed    }
}
```

I've reinstated the original parameter names (`s` and `lim`) in place of your `line` and `maxline`.

There's a specialized version of `getline()` on p32 with no arguments.  There's a slightly compressed version of the code above on p69.  There's another implementation on p165 in terms of `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because your function is not returning anything when it doesn't enter the for loop.

Update it as :

```
int getline(char line[], int maxline){

  int c, i;

  for(i = 0; i<maxline-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; i++){

     line[i] = c;
      if (c=='\n'){
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
      }

      line[i] ='\0';
      return i;

    }

    return 0; #return some appropriate value when doesn't enter in for loop.
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't return anything if you encounter EOF before you fill the buffer or get a newline.  Further, in that case, the string is not null terminated, so you can't reliably work out where the end was.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes. The answer is just help with warning. I'm not sure the `for` loop is correct, as it by default returns once entered, it doesn't loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int getline(char line[], int maxline)
{
    int i = 0, c;

    for(; i < maxline-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; i++)
        line[i] = c;

    if (c == '\n') 
        s[i++] = c;

    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

This should be enough. The code had unneeded brace due to which it would have returned the value in the first iteration, if it had executed.